# does php mem_get_usage( ) include database memory?

Tags: php, mysql

Very simple question, does php mem_get_usage( ) include database memory?  In my script the size of the data arrays and memory probably needed by MySQL is much larger than any globals/namespaces etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, this show PHP-only memory usage. MySQL has it's own counters and limitations.

Comment: On MySQL, `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS` will tell you more about the operational parameters. That is unless you're crazy enough to be using MyISAM, in which case you may need to look at that instead.